# Disable input calls if cursor position is not inside element BoundingRectangle

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting the automation element on windows using mouse cordinates(x &y)

```
static Rect m_bRect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(new Point((double)Cursor.Position.X, (double)Cursor.Position.Y));
m_bRect = element.Current.BoundingRectangle;
```

i want to achieve one functionality that if user cursor position is not inside element Boundingrectangle then Block the input calls using API user32.dll, for that i have written below code on mouse down operation.

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void BlockInput([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool fBlockIt);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref POINT p);

private void HookManager_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            POINT l_objPoint = new POINT();
            bool l_bretVal = GetCursorPos(ref l_objPoint);

          while (!m_bRect .Contains(l_objPoint.X, l_objPoint.Y)
          {
           BlockInput(true);
           break;
          }
       }
```

But above code is not working as expected, it takes user clicks even if user cursor is not inside automation element boundingrectangle.

I have also tried another approach using timer tick please check below code but here Automationelement is not captured correctly.

```
      private void OnHovering()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timerOnHover = new     System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            _timerOnHover.Tick += new EventHandler(_timerOnHovering_Tick);
            _timerOnHover.Interval = 100;
            _timerOnHover.Start();

        }

        private void _timerOnHovering_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            POINT currentPoint = new POINT();
            bool l_bretVal = GetCursorPos(ref currentPoint);
            if (!l_bretVal)
            {
                return;
            }
                if (!m_bRect.Contains(currentPoint.X, currentPoint.Y && !ISmouseMove)

                {
                    BlockInput(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    BlockInput(false);
                }
            }               
        }
```